# Measures on infinite-dimensional spaces

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $M$ be the set of all signed measures on $[0,1]$, and $\Delta$ be the set of all probability measures on the same space (equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). As discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214473/compact-subset-of-infinite-dimensional-space-has-empty-interior), $\Delta$ has an empty interior as a subset of $M$ as a metric space (using the metric induced by any norm, such as the total variation norm, e.g., also discussed in the first answer to the linked question.) My question is, how will I describe the fact that "almost all" elements of $M$ lie outside $\Delta$?

This is just an example, and the same would apply to say, e.g., that "allmost no" continuous function on $[0,1]$ is linear.

In other words, I'm looking for an appropriate measure on infinite dimensional spaces to be able to present the statements correctly in this way. I know that an analog of the Lebesgue measure for infinite-dimensional spaces does not exist.  But in my statements (this  is necessary for my research) it is essential that I bring out that the infinite dimensional sets I'm talking about forms a "measure-0" subset of some bigger set.

Comment: See Here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9210220. Also, there is the notion of meager sets connected to the Baire category theorem.